# how to build a local npm repository on a windows server without using couchdb or any other 3rd party tools

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I need to deploy an npm repository into a secure, no-internet-access-ever enclave. I also need to be able to update these packages manually (again, never internet access) by downloading and updating the node_modules directory from install packages (after they've been scanned). I also can't use any third-party tools to do any of this, so no CouchDB or Bit or Verdaccio or Sinopia.

I'm still pretty new to node.js and npm, and I'm on Windows boxes. I have PowerShell, but not a regular command window.

I'm sure someone somewhere has done this, but I can't seem to locate ANY docs after weeks of searching. So, I'm asking if someone could maybe help build a process to accomplish this, something that I can share with even-less-experienced developers than myself. Or possibly point me to a basic walkthrough someone else has done.

Comment: Why do you think Verdaccio does not apply to your requirements?

Comment: Verdaccio is a "named package", and would have to stand up to my area's security whitelist, which it wouldn't. (It's a small list.) I can use javascript, and I'm betting Verdaccio is really just a JS package, but that's what I'm up against. Vanilla JS good, named packages UNSAFE.